# Java JList How To Handle Different Model Classes?

Tags: java, swing, switch-statement

I have a Jlist and it's model class can differ. And I want to take action according to JList's model class. I tried something like this:

```
        private void jList1ValueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {                                    
        Object selectedObject = jList1.getModel().getClass();
        switch (selectedObject) {

        case ResponsePlayerSearch.class:
            //do something with this class. for example run get player function from this class:
            selectedObject.getPlayerName();
            break;
        case ResponseLeagueSearch.class:
            //do something with this class
            break;
        case ResponseTeamSearch.class:
            //do something with this class
            break;
        case ResponseCoachSearch.class:
            //do something with this class
            break;
        default:
            

    }

}
```

But ide throws an error : `patterns in switch statements are a preview feature and are disabled by default. (use --enable-preview to enable patterns in switch statements)`

How should I handle a situation like this? Should I use switch case or something else? Or how should I use switch case for handling different classes?

Edit(To give more details) :
Basically what I'm doing is searching some values from an api. First, users have to select a type(team,player,league or coach) and according to this type they can search any word they want. So as an example, let's say user searched for a team. Then program makes the call and getting the response. Then this response is converting to a model. Which is `ResponseTeamSearch` for this type. After that JList's model class is changing according to this model. Then JList is getting populated by the values of response.

By the way this is the creation code of Jlist:

```
jList1 = new javax.swing.JList();
 jList1.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTIO;

jList1.addListSelectionListener(new 
javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener() {
  public void valueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent 
evt) 
{
    jList1ValueChanged(evt);
  }
    });

  jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jList1);
```

Comment: This sounds like an XY Problem and I wonder if your entire approach could be wrong. A guess, that you wouldn't have a single listener handling a variety of models and perhaps would swap listeners inside of the event that makes you swap models, but as for specific answers, I am betting that that would require a much more specific and detailed question.

Comment: So, questions for you: Are your program concerns well separated in a model-view arrangement? If not, then that is probably a root contributing factor to this current problem. If so, then the solution is likely to be found in the model code, not in the view code. Again, unless you want poorly created cosmetic fixes (like the current answer), please tell much more of the pertinent details of your problem and your code and show more code, preferably a [mre].

Comment: I've just edited the question. I can give more details of course.

Comment: My guess: you would probably want to solve this using a State or Command Design Pattern, where the state could be defined by an enum and state change would be triggered by when the user selected the type.

Comment: Can you show an example for that? Also I've added the creation code of Jlist1, I don't use a type parameter while creation as you can see.

Comment: There are already many examples of use of common design patterns in Java. If you want something more specific to your problem, better for *you* first to create and post in your question your [mre] (as requested above). Otherwise, anything that I create would have likely been something created and posted here many times before. If you have any questions about how to create a decent MRE, then please comment back.

Comment: One idea would be to create separate `JLists` for player, league, coach, and team.  Use a `CardLayout` to switch between the different `JLists`.

Comment: I'll try that first. Probably that will work, let's see.